# Xamarin Forms Shell is there anyway to remove the navigation bar but keep the hamburger icon?

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there anyway to allow content to touch the top of the screen while keeping the hamburger icon. In the example below, imagine the blue background was an image, I want the blue to touch the top of the screen and have the hamburger icon overlay over the top:
[image: Example 1]

I've tried the following but it just changes the colour of the bar:

```
<Shell 
       BackgroundColor="Transparent">
```

If there is no way to hide just the bar, is there anyway to hide the bar and the hamburger icon and then add the icon back manually?

EDIT:
I tried but it removed the hamburger icon as well. Is there anyway to add the hamburger icon back?:

```
Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
```

EDIT:
Just seen this implentation which is what I need but is there anyway to do this with Xamarin Shell:
https://xamgirl.com/transparent-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms/

RESOLUTION:
This has now been moved to the [Xamarin Forms GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9243)

Comment: No, the hamburger is inside the navbar.

Comment: Is there no way with custom rendereres to remove it from the navbar?

Comment: [Sure](https://adrianszen.com/2017/03/22/how-to-implement-hamburger-menu-in-xamarin-forms/) read into that... My comment was in response to `is there anyway to remove the navigation bar but keep the hamburger icon` and there's not.

Comment: https://xamgirl.com/transparent-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @AndroDevil This is for a navigationPage but Shell doesn't use navigation pages. Is there anyway to implement this for Shell?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to implement it . The style had been set in default in shell .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT is there anyway to overwrite the default implementation. Also, @ everyone can you give me feedback on my questions.

Comment: @RyanGaudion did you found a soliton? I've tried the Lucas Zhang suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: @Gold.strike unfortunately not. I had to create a navigation menu myself without the use of shell

Comment: @RyanGaudion that means that you have remove the NavigationBar from Shell with `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"`and add your own NavigationBar?

Comment: @Gold.strike. unfortunately I didn't even manage to do that. I instead created a brand new Xamarin Application without any Shell and had to create a navigation bar that navigated between pages using the normal navigation methods. No Shell in the application at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the style of Shell navigation bar in **Resource Dictionary**

```
   <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />  // set navigation bar as Transparent
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll try this. Can you show a screenshot of what it looks like on your device?

Comment: You could share your sample, it works fine on my side .